# CentOS7 QUOTA xfs

Tags: centos, grub, fstab, xfs, quota

I can not enable disk quotas for */home* (*/dev/md2*). For */* (*/dev/md1*) it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

```
cat /etc/fstab
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
/dev/md1 / xfs defaults 0 0
/dev/md2 /home xfs defaults,uquota 0 0
```

---

```
mount|grep quota
/dev/md1 on / type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,usrquota)
/dev/md2 on /home type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,sunit=1024,swidth=2048,noquota)
```

---

```
cat /boot/grub2/grub.cfg|grep quota
linux16 /boot/vmlinuz-x.x.x-grsec root=/dev/md1 ro net.ifnames=0 rd.auto rd.auto=1 rhgb quiet rd.md.uuid=4ed85ae0:2334zc39:b3e2acc2:21fd5312 rootflags=uquota
```

Answer (score 0):

you made mistake in /etc/fstab syntax that's why it is not working 
syntax is describe as follows

/dev/md1              /           xfs          defaults        0      0
blockpoint     mountpoint    filesystem     modeofopration   dump     fsck

you add extra entry ",uquota" that is undefine for fstab